# what is "java remoting" ? Does it mean RMI?

Tags: java, web-services, rmi

I have read some articles about java. It use "java remoting", but I cannot find a Wikipedia page for this concept.

Does it only mean RMI?

What does the "remoting" mean? if it means "communication" then can we call TCP/IP is a kind of "remoting" ?

Comment: More context please. Links to articles would be a good start.

Comment: http://daniel.gredler.net/2008/01/07/java-remoting-protocol-benchmarks/

Comment: @gizmo see: http://www.infoq.com/cn/articles/lp-java-remoting-1/

Comment: @lovespring I cannot read Chineese, but the titles of the article seem to explicitly mention various alternatives to perform remote calls, namely RMI, EJB and Web Services.

Comment: Remoting is a general term, normally meaning the concept of communicating with objects in a particular language/platform from the outside (e.g. via RMI over TCP/IP or HTTP, or something else)

Comment: I'd call any method of **directly-ish** calling code "remoting". So, RMI would be remoting, as would arguably SOAP. Making a request to a webapp that returns HTML content, less so. (Even though, obviously, ultimately that request gets routed to some code.) REST would be on the fence. It's not an unambigous term, and I'd say it refers more to what you're trying to do, conceptually, than what the specific technology is. So, some use of networking is remoting, but not any use of it, unless you're abusing semantics.

Comment: With "directly-ish", I mean there's a more or less straightforward mapping between the URL and the invoked method, and between the on-the-wire input format and the parameters of said method. (SOAP is arguable because it usually involves binding to a XML document, but the intent with SOAP is to have an interoperable data representation, not a programming model completely unrelated to an mainstream programming language.)